# Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance, React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm refactoring a sample shopping cart project from `useState` to `useReducer`.

In the `ADD_TO_CART` case of the `cartReducer`, I try and add an `item object` into the `cart` array, but I receive `Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance.` What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-cdn-3musx?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should return the entire state, not the individual state.

```
const cartReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "ADD_TO_CART":
      return { cart: [...state.cart, action.item] };
    default:
      throw new Error();
  }
};
```

Comment: Sorry, doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Did you try to test? I did on codesandbox you provided and it worked well. Again, you can test again as `return {...state, cart: [...state.cart, action.item] };`

Comment: Still nothing, unfortunately. Could you send the link to the working sandbox?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-jepsen-e6ece

Comment: On this link, you will see there is no occurring error like yours.

Comment: Gotcha, I appreciate your help!